# textAreaInput is not working with fileInput

Tags: shiny

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",multiple = TRUE,accept = c("text/csv","text/comma-        separated-values,text/plain", ".csv")), 
textAreaInput("paste", "Or manufacturer", "Paste one manufacturer per line"),),
mainPanel(tableOutput("contents"))))
 server <- function(input, output) {
output$contents <- renderTable({
 if(!is.null(input$file1))
 {
 req(input$file1)
data <- as.matrix(mpg)
df <- read.delim(input$file1$datapath,header = F)
manufacturer <- unique(df[, 1])
data[data[, 1] %in% manufacturer, ]}
else
{
 req(input$file1)
 paste_data <-({ input$paste })
 write.table(paste_data,"111")
 data <- as.matrix(mpg)
 manufacturer <- unique(paste_data[, 1])
 data[data[, 1] %in% manufacturer, ]
}})}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I used the above code to allow the user to input as two types, One is from the file and second is to paste some inputs. I used mpg data (ggplot2::mpg) as reference. But the code is only working when user input via file, if user is paste some input as like this

```
audi
dodge
ford
```

not showing anything. Why is textAreaInput not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below. Use `observeEvent` instead of `if else`. Also, i have added a conditional panel. For the text input, if you ask the input to be comma or space separated, you can simplify your text data conversion to a table using 'strsplit'

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("choose","Choose file source",choices = c("file","text"),selected = NULL),
      conditionalPanel("input.choose=='file'",fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",multiple = TRUE,accept = c("text/csv","text/comma-        separated-values,text/plain", ".csv"))),
      conditionalPanel("input.choose=='text'",
                       p("Enter a comma or space separated list"),
                       textAreaInput("paste", "Or manufacturer",placeholder =  "Paste one manufacturer per line"),)),
      
    mainPanel(tableOutput("contents"))))
server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$file1,{
    req(input$file1)
    output$contents=renderTable({data <- as.matrix(mpg)
                                df <- read.delim(input$file1$datapath,header = F)
                                manufacturer <- unique(df[, 1])
                                data[data[, 1] %in% manufacturer, ]})
    })
  
observeEvent(input$paste,{
  req(input$paste)
  mfg=strsplit(input$paste,",| ")
  output$contents=renderTable(data.frame('manfucature'=unlist(mfg)))
  
})
  
  }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```